# Continuity of Helmholtz-Hodge projection in $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (for simplicity $d = 2$ or $3$) be a bounded Lipschitz domain. For any vector-valued function $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbf{L}^2(\Omega):= \left ( L^2(\Omega) \right )^d$, one can uniquely write 
$$ \mathbf{f} = \nabla \phi + \mathbf{w}_{\mathbf{f}},$$
where $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\mathbf{w}_{\mathbf{f}} \in W:= \left \{ \mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{L}^2(\Omega): \int_\Omega \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \phi ~ dx= 0 \text{ for all } \phi \in H_0^1(\Omega) \right \}$. In particular, the function $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies the following variational form:

$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \varphi ~ dx = \int_\Omega \mathbf{f} \cdot \nabla \varphi \quad \text{for all } \varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega).
$$

Based on this (Helmholtz-Hodge) decomposition, one can define a mapping $\mathbb{P}: \mathbf{f} \mapsto \mathbf{w}_{\mathbf{f}}$. This mapping is obviously linear and bounded in the sense of $\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)$. In particular, there is a generic constant $C>0$ such that

$$ \|\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{f})\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)} \leq \|\mathbf{f} \|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)}$$

for any $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)$.

My question: if we restrict the domain of the mapping $\mathbb{P}$ to be a subspace of $\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)$, say $\mathbf{H}_0^1(\Omega) := \left ( H_0^1(\Omega) \right )^d$, can we show the boundedness of the restricted mapping in the sense of $\mathbf{H}_0^1(\Omega)$ (with respect to the $\mathbf{H}_0^1(\Omega)$ semi-norm $\|\mathbf{v} \|_{\mathbf{H}_0^1(\Omega)}^2 := \int_\Omega |\nabla \mathbf{v} |^2~ dx$ for any $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{H}_0^1(\Omega)$)? Or under which additional assumptions can we show such a boundedness result of this projection mapping?

Comment: do you want to add a boundary condition to $ \phi$?  you can make it zero... then  if you write out the pde that $ \phi$ satisfies  stuff becomes more apparent (or at least for me the pde always helps me)

Comment: @Math604 I have added the corresponding variational form for the function $\phi$. It doesn't matter for the boundary condition of the function $\phi$, but it is okay to include it.

Comment: i admit i haven't read the question carefully... but $ \phi$ satisfies $ -\Delta \phi= div(f)$ in $ \Omega$ with $ \phi=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.  So from this you can get estimates on $ \phi$ and since we have $  f = \nabla \phi + w$  you can now get estimates on $ w$.    I am not sure whether it gives you want you want...but i would try this

Comment: @Math604 Yes, you are right. Yet I am interested in the estimate of $\mathbf{w}_\mathbf{f}$ in the semi-$H^1$ norm. Under some suitable regularity assumptions, I wonder if we have it hold: $\| \mathbf{w}_{\mathbf{f}} \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \|\mathbf{f}\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$?

Comment: so it looks like you need to estimate the H^1 norm of $\nabla \phi$.. which should controlled by the $H^2$ norm of $ \phi$.   So by elliptic regularity it appears you want the $L^2$ norm of div(f) .... so at least formally it seems you get want you want...but i guess one needs to try and write things out a bit...